# how to add Json config to particle js

Tags: json, particles.js

I've installed particle.js in my project and it works with the default effect, I have gone through this site http://vincentgarreau.com and found 5 effects: `default`, `snow`, `NASA`, `Buddle` and `Nyan cat`. My question is how can I use those effects in my project? I choose one and I downloaded the JSON config but I don't know how to add it to my project.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to load the json file. The syntax would be something like this

```
<script>
  particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function(){
    console.log('particles.json loaded...');
  });
</script>
```

Write the appropriate path if these files are located elsewhere. The 'particles.json' file will be your config file you downloaded from somewhere. You can even edit the particles.json file yourself to get your desired result.

This video by Traversy media is a great reference if you wish to dig deep into particle js and create your own desired effects.
Good luck!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK3cgD09Qf0&t=1567s